# How to reuse text in an HTML page, where the text is defined on the same page (not a different file)?

Tags: html

In HTML, I want to define a block of text in the page, and then reuse the text multiple times on the same page.  Can I do this using HTML only?

I specifically *don't* want the duplicated content to live in another file.  I want it to be defined in the same page.  Like declaring a constant at the top of a code file and reusing it throughout your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/ lists some other options too. The way you'd achieve this is to move the text you want duplicated to a separate file, and then include that new file everywhere you want the duplicate text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript inside your HTML Document, so you don't need an extra page. Just define the variable inside a `<script>` tag (best way would be to do it in the header, but it also works in the body) and then access the value of the variable inside another `<script>` tag in the body like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var carName = "Volvo";  <!-- defining the variable -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>

   <p id="demo">Hi.</p>

   <script>
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = carName;  <!-- changing the Hi in the <p> tag to Volvo (value of the variable -->
   </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Oh boy, that's the first question I was able to answer ^^

Comment: But tbh, simply duplicating your text seems more practical.

Comment: Thanks! Let me test this.

Answer (score 0):

You just duplicate your text couple of times in your html code.  You should usually use the p tag.

Comment: We want to define the text as a constant, and then reuse it, so that if we have to change it, we only have to change it in one place, and the change gets picked up everywhere.

Comment: HTML in not programming language; it's a coding language. It doesn't have variables. If you want to declare a constant variable as a string you should use javascript with html. So either use javascript to use variables or use easier and better ways like jquery. I personally don't like javascript because if it's useless syntax. A lot of people use jquery. Also if you want to use a text couple of times you must code it in html file or use javascript or use both frontend and back end with php mysql or asp.net or etc

Comment: Thanks that's helpful